# Find duration between 2 events in splunk

Tags: splunk

Splunk query:

```
index=* host="TMP-2001" | transaction id startswith="Start mode" endswith="Stop mode" | chart count by timestamp
```

I'm using id because its the most consistent id through all my logs.
**Start mode** and **Stop mode** are the name of the events.

Currently my query is just showing my all the timestamps but what I'm trying to get the **duration in seconds** between the 2 events ?

Each log has the following:

```
   id: TEMP_1
   event: Start mode
   level: debug
   timestamp: 2023-03-28T16:38:43.323-0400
```

Next log and so on....

```
    id: TEMP_1
   event: Stop mode
   level: debug
   timestamp: 2023-03-28T16:38:41.802-0400
```

Answer (score 1):

`| transaction` is not intuitive or reliable. I tend to avoid it where possible. You'll find that a lot of other questions about this command have answers that tend to steer people away from it too.

That being said, can you achieve the same result with this SPL instead?

```
| search "Start mode" OR "Stop mode"
| stats min(_time) as _time, range(_time) as duration by id
| timechart max(duration) as duration
```

If you really do want to use `| transaction` then it should be working with this SPL:

```
| search "Start mode" OR "Stop mode"
| transaction id startswith="Start mode" endswith="Stop mode"
| timechart max(duration) as duration
```

If this doesn't work, make sure that `| transaction` is returning results. Transaction needs to receive events in reverse time order. If it's possible that your event order has been modified you can enforce it with:
`| sort - _time` immediately before your `| transaction`.

Don't forget to update the `| timechart span=` argument accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume the `id` field is unique?

If so, you can improve on @[Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21282417/tom)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75871897/4418) thusly:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp ("start mode" OR "stop mode")
| stats min(_time) as start max(_time) as end by id
| eval duration=end-start
| eval start=strftime(start,"%c"), end=strftime(end,"%c")
```

`strftime`/`strptime` reference (`%c` is my most common `strftime` formatting code because it's usually good enough and/or what I would have specified manually anyway) - https://strftime.org

---

#### edit

I prefer to subtract the `min` from `max` time instead of using `range` because I usually need all of them, and doing it explicitly makes reading the SPL easier when I (or someone else) comes back to it in the future